# Draw a rectangle around a control, C++ MFC

Tags: mfc, dialog, controls

I have the code

```
    HWND hWndTmp = pDX->m_pDlgWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
    hWndTmp = GetDlgItem(hWndTmp, pDX->m_idLastControl);
    CWnd *wnd;
    wnd = wnd->FromHandle(hWndTmp);
    RECT wndRect;
    wnd->GetWindowRect(&wndRect);
```

Which gives me the rectangle around the control described in pDX.

What I would like to do is draw a rectangle around this control a few times to draw the users eyes to it. I have searched for a while on how I could do this but nothing seems to actually work for me.

I've tried this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx8yykw8.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

But it tells me "System" cannout be found or is not real.

Is there a simple way given the coordinates to draw a rectangle?

Comment: The link you've provided is for managed C++.

Comment: Thats probably why it didnt work. And I really am not sure of the differences between all the I guess "dialects". I hear MFC, managed, Win32, CLI. I never learned any of this, only the language itself. I have tried to learn it many times but all the tutorials speak about each thing specifically and nothing gives an entire overview.

Comment: If that dialog is yours (i.e. not third party, i.e. you have its code) you should do that kinda stuff by overriding `OnPaint`

Comment: About your confusion with the Windows GUI toolkits, a brief overview: Win32 is the basic, unmanaged api. MFC is an unmanaged, object oriented layer over that. In Windows jargon, unmanaged means not controlled by the .NET virtual machine. Unmanaged code compiles to native assembly code. Managed code compiles to MSIL, which is similar to the Java bytecode, except that this runs on .NET's virtual machine. And finally, managed C++, aka C++/CLI, is a language which extends C++ in order to write wrappers between unmanaged and managed code.

Comment: The DlgItem it gets can be of many different types. This code is in a validation function, I want to inform the user that this control cannot be validated by flickering something over the control. EDIT: Thanks for that rundown.

Comment: If that's the case, I believe you could get the control's DC somehow, associate it with a `Graphics` object and then call `DrawRectangle` for that object. I have some code which does that, but now I'll go for lunch. I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Ok, I think that will get me somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to get the screen rectangle of the control and convert it to your Dialog's client, and override `OnPaint` for the dialog, and draw the rectangle there (slightly inflated).  This will mean you'll definitely see it, and not interfere with the painting of the control itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, go with Moo-Juice's solution. It separates concerns better, IMHO. But if you need a quick fix, try this

```
CClientDC drawingContext( pDX );
RECT wndRect;
wnd->GetWindowRect(&wndRect);
//Shrink wndRect before if needed
CPoint rectPoints[5];
rectPoints[0] = CPoint( wndRect.left, wndRect.top );
rectPoints[1] = CPoint( wndRect.right, wndRect.top );
rectPoints[2] = CPoint( wndRect.right, wndRect.bottom );
rectPoints[3] = CPoint( wndRect.left, wndRect.bottom );
rectPoints[4] = rectPoints[0];
CPen* oldPen = drawingContext.SelectStockObject(RED_PEN);
drawingContext.Polyline(rectPoints, 5);
drawingContext.SelectObject( oldPen );
```

If you don't see the rect, try shrinking it a little so it doesn't overlap with the dialog's border.

Comment: Sadly this does nothing. Well I mean it doesn't throw an error, but it is not visible on the control.

Comment: Did you try shrinking the rect? As in `wndRect.left = wndRect.left + 5; wndRect.right = wndRect.right-5;` and so on?

Comment: The problem might be that when the dialog is repainted, the rectangle gets cleared because it's not part of the dialog. That's why you need to do it by overriding `OnPaint`. My solution works in my old code because my custom dialog ignores repaint requests.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a brush is for filling and a pen is for lines. Besides, the `DrawEdge` method uses the Windows theme pen. Using `Polyline` lets you use a custom pen. Try that (updated my answer again). If it fails, you'll  have to override `OnPaint`.

Comment: Looks like I got yours working. Gotta do some playing around but it will work just fine for me.